# Hibernate assigning incorrect database ID's

Tags: java, hibernate

Here's the situation: I have a mapping table, let's call it SecurityContact, with three columns.

1. The first column(let's call it security_id) contains the primary key for SecurityContact. Hibernate successfully auto-generates an ID number for this column.
2. The second column(let's call it agent_id) contains the value of the primary key of a second table (let's call it AgentContact), whose primary key column is called contact_id. This agent_id column, with the referenced column contact_id, as you may have guessed, is one of the join columns between SecurityContact and AgentContact.
3. The third column of SecurityContact(let's call it audit_id) also contains the value of a primary key of AgentContact. This is also a join column between SecurityContact and AgentContact, with again the referenced column contact_id within AgentContact. The relationship between entries in SecurityContact and entries in AgentContact is many to one.

So basically, this SecurityContact table connects agent_id and audit_id to security_id. agent_id and audit_id can be the same or different, depending on whether the two entries in AgentContact are the same or different.

Now here's the problem: Even when the two entries are different, Hibernate seems to put the same id for both of them, this id being the contact_id of the auditContact of the SecurityContact. The two entries should be different, with agent_id containing the contact_id of the agent, and audit_id containing the contact_id of the audit (from the same table, AgentContact). Anyone have any idea why?

My apologies in advance for being so long winded. Here is the code for SecurityContact:

```
 /**
 * The persistent class for the SecurityContact database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@FXClass(kind=FXClassKind.REMOTE)
public class SecurityContact implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Transient private String uid;
    @FXIgnore
    public String getUid() {
        if (uid == null) {
            uid = "" + securityId;
        }
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="security_id")
    private Long securityId;

    @Column(name="create_date")
    private String createDate;

    @Column(name="create_user")
    private String createUser;

    @Column(name="modify_date")
    private String modifyDate;

    @Column(name="modify_user")
    private String modifyUser;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AgentContact
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="agent_id", referencedColumnName="contact_id")
    private AgentContact agentContact;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AuditContact
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="audit_id", referencedColumnName="contact_id")
    private AgentContact auditContact;

    public SecurityContact() {
    }
    @FXKeyColumn
    public Long getSecurityId() {
        return this.securityId;
    }

    public void setSecurityId(Long securityId) {
        this.securityId = securityId;
    }

    public String getCreateDate() {
        return this.createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(String createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public String getCreateUser() {
        return this.createUser;
    }

    public void setCreateUser(String createUser) {
        this.createUser = createUser;
    }

    public String getModifyDate() {
        return this.modifyDate;
    }

    public void setModifyDate(String modifyDate) {
        this.modifyDate = modifyDate;
    }

    public String getModifyUser() {
        return this.modifyUser;
    }

    public void setModifyUser(String modifyUser) {
        this.modifyUser = modifyUser;
    }
    @FXManyToOne(parent="com.counterpartcontacts.entity.AgentContact", property="contactId")
    public AgentContact getAgentContact() {
        return this.agentContact;
    }

    public void setAgentContact(AgentContact agentContact) {
        this.agentContact = agentContact;
    }
    @FXManyToOne(parent="com.counterpartcontacts.entity.AgentContact", property="contactId")
    public AgentContact getAuditContact() {
        return this.auditContact;
    }

    public void setAuditContact(AgentContact auditContact) {
        this.auditContact = auditContact;
    }

}
```

Here is the code for the AgentContact table:

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the AgentContact database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@FXClass(kind=FXClassKind.REMOTE)
public class AgentContact implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Transient private String uid;
    @FXIgnore
    public String getUid() {
        if (uid == null) {
            uid = "" + contactId;
        }
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="contact_id")
    private Long contactId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="bank_id")
    private Bank bank;

//  @Column(name="bank_id")
    //private String bank2;

    @Column(name="create_date")
    private String createDate;

    @Column(name="create_user")
    private String createUser;

    private String email;

    private String fax;

    @Column(name="modify_date")
    private String modifyDate;

    @Column(name="modify_user")
    private String modifyUser;

    private String name;

    private String phone;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to SecurityContact
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="agentContact")
    private Set<SecurityContact> securityContacts;


    public AgentContact() {
    }
    @FXKeyColumn
    public Long getContactId() {
        return this.contactId;
    }

    public void setContactId(Long contactId) {
        this.contactId = contactId;
    }
    @FXManyToOne(parent="com.counterpartcontacts.entity.Bank", property="bankId")
    public Bank getBank() {
        return this.bank;
    }

    public void setBank(Bank bank) {
        this.bank = bank;
    }

    public String getCreateDate() {
        return this.createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(String createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public String getCreateUser() {
        return this.createUser;
    }

    public void setCreateUser(String createUser) {
        this.createUser = createUser;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFax() {
        return this.fax;
    }

    public void setFax(String fax) {
        this.fax = fax;
    }

    public String getModifyDate() {
        return this.modifyDate;
    }

    public void setModifyDate(String modifyDate) {
        this.modifyDate = modifyDate;
    }

    public String getModifyUser() {
        return this.modifyUser;
    }

    public void setModifyUser(String modifyUser) {
        this.modifyUser = modifyUser;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return this.phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    @FXOneToMany(fillArguments="contactId")
    public Set<SecurityContact> getSecurityContacts() {
        return this.securityContacts;
    }

    public void setSecurityContacts(Set<SecurityContact> securityContacts) {
        this.securityContacts = securityContacts;
    }


}
```

Comment: *The third column of SecurityContact(let's call it audit_id) also contains the value of a primary key of SecurityContact* is this a typo?

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was not on the Hibernate side, but on the Flex side. There was a race condition forming between DataCollection synchronizations. Adding a sleep function resolved the issue.